# Easymock matcher on return value

Tags: java, easymock

foo.toString() returns

```
"[id: <id>, stuffIdontCareAbout: 0]"
```

I want to test that the id is correct, but everything else in the string can have any value. This is what I tried:

```
expect(foo.toString()).andReturn(EasyMock.find("[id: 42,"));
```

but here's how it complained:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception usually occurs when matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a method:
    foo(5, eq(6));  // wrong
You need to use no matcher at all or a matcher for every single param:
     foo(eq(5), eq(6)); // right
     foo(5, 6); // also right
```

So, how do I use an EasyMock matcher on a return value?

Comment: I don't understand. You're mocking `foo`. `foo.toString()` will return whatever you tell it to return.

Comment: O. Yeah, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a mock. It seems you only want to test the result of `foo.toString()`.

Using AssertJ (which I recommend), would mean doing

```
assertThat(foo.toString()).startsWith("[id: 42,");
```